# Remove part of a string using regex in python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to clean up some info in a csv of transactions from a credit card statement, all of the transaction names are formatted as follows:

`AplPay SUBWAY       SCOTTSDALE          AZ`
`POPEYES 8703 0000   TEMPE               AZ`
`SALAD AND GO #1138 0PHOENIX             AZ`

The transactions names all have multiple spaces followed by a state abbreviation at the end, the number of spaces is different each time as it is used to make all of the state abbreviations line up. Would using a regex pattern to remove these be the correct course or is there a better option?

Currently I am building a list of the transactions from this specific credit card:

```
AmextransList = []
fileName = 'amexActivityJune.csv'
cnt = 0
with open(fileName, newline='') as csvfile:
  spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
  for row in spamreader:
    if cnt != 0:
      AmextransList.append(transaction(row[1], row[0], row[2]))
      

    cnt += 1
```

In the transaction class I have a method to clean the name, **transaction.cleanTransaction()** where I would like to do the cleaning of the names.

Here is the transaction class currently:

```
class transaction:
  name = ""
  date = ""
  amount = ""
  def __init__(self, n, d, a):
    self.name = n
    self.date = d
    self.amount = a
  def printTransaction(self):
    print("Name: ", self.name, " Amount: ", self.amount, " Date: ", self.date)


  def cleanTransaction(self): #This is where I need help
    #Remove the ______________AZ from the name
    #More work not for StackOverFlow :)
```

Comment: What is the actual format of the source file `amexActivityJune.csv` and how should it look like after the clean up?

Answer (score 1):

To place only 1 space between each word :

```py
s = 'SALAD AND GO #1138 0PHOENIX             AZ'
clean = " ".join(s.split())
print(clean)  # SALAD AND GO #1138 0PHOENIX AZ
```

`s.split()` returns a list of words in `s`.

`" ".join()` is then used to join all the words in the list into a string with one space between each word.